# Try to insert image inside div using function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I want to make gallery view using  jqtouch  js library so I try to insert image using function  the it show nothing but when am not using function then it work properly , also used document.getElementById("#").innerHTML it nor working when I simply insert image it show so plz help

```
    <script>

    function fun(){
            $("#thumbs_container").append('<ul id="thumbs"      class="thumbView" style="display:none;"><li class="pic"><a   href="#photo_container"><img                               src="thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg" title="this is a description"/></a></li></ul>');
    }
    </script>

    <body  onLoad="fun();">
    <div id="about" class="selectable">
        <p><img src="codropsIcon.png"/></p>
        <p>
            <strong>Wonderwall Image Gallery</strong>
            <a href="http://www.codrops.com">By Codrops</a>
        </p>
        <p>A web app created with <br /> <strong>jQTouch</strong></p>
        <p><br /><br /><a href="#" class="grayButton goback">Close</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- The list of images (thumbs) -->
    <div id="thumbs_container" class="current">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>Thumbs</h1>
            <a class="button slideup" id="infoButton" href="#about">About</a>
        </div>


        <!--<ul id="thumbs" class="thumbView" style="display:none;">
            <li class="pic"><a href="#photo_container"><img        src="thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg" title="this is a description"/></a></li>
            <li class="pic"><a href="#photo_container"><img src="thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/2.jpg" title="great!"/></a></li>

        </ul>-->




    </div>
    <!-- The single image container -->
    <div id="photo_container">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>Photo</h1>
            <a class="back" href="#thumbs_container">Photos</a>
            <a class="button slideup" id="infoButton" href="#about">About</a>
        </div>
        <div class="loader" style="display:none;"></div>
        <div id="theimage" class="singleimage"></div>
        <div class="descriptionWrapper">
            <p id="description"></p>
            <div id="prev" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div id="next" style="display:none;"></div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `style="display:none;` set within your function. Remove this and it should work ok.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to include jQuery in your page. Maybe you copypasted just an part of your file, but make sure you do something like this to include jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

2) The HTML you are appending has the following attribute:

```
style="display:none;"
```

So even if this works, you will not see the image.

3) Finally, make sure the image you are trying to show exists.